# unexpected behaviour when comparing modification time of files in python

Tags: python, file

I have a recursive loop for transfering files from location A to B in python, and I thought the code was working well by not copying files with the same name and modification time.

My surprise came when comparing modification times. This is part of the code:

```
if os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, file)) != os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(Dest_Dir, os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), Source_Dir))):
   print 'Path A - date: ', os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, file))
   print 'to'
   print 'Path B - date: ', os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(Dest_Dir, os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), Source_Dir))) 
   print '\n'
   shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(Dest_Dir, os.path.join(os.path.relpath(root, Source_Dir), file)))
   print 'Copied modified file ', os.path.join(root, file)
```

I manually copied all files from location A to B so that no files should be copied with this script.

However, when I print the results, although the float `mtime` is the same for all files, the `!=` condition is satisfied and all files are copied. This is the result:

```
Path A - date: 1453715636.69
to
Path B - date: 1453715636.69
Copied modified file  X:\path\to\file\test.txt
```

Is it because I am comparing floats and they are actually not exactly the same number?

Comment: yes, float can be the problem. But you can check paths.

Comment: BTW, your code appears to calculate the same thing multiple times, eg `os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(Dest_Dir, os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), Source_Dir)))`. This is both inefficient and confusing to people reading your code, since they have to check that the repeated codes are actually identical. See [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Thats true, thank you